# Yii2 - update doesn't work

Tags: yii, yii2

I am trying to update two field, but the update isn't working for some reason.
This is the method:

```
public function actionChangepassword()
    {
        $model = $this->findModel(Yii::$app->user->identity->id);

        $model->scenario = 'changepassword';

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())):
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

            if(ActiveForm::validate($model))
                return ActiveForm::validate($model);

            $model->salt     = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(32);
            $model->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->salt . $model->password_new);

            $model->update();

            return 'true';
        endif;

        return $this->renderAjax('changePassword',
               [ 'model' => $model]
            );
    }
```

and JS function:

```
$('body').on('beforeSubmit', '#changePassword', function(event, jqXHR, settings) {
        var form = $(this);
        if(form.find('.has-error').length) {
                return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: 'post',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                        // do something ...
                }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

I am getting **true** as result, which means that the function it self is working, but the password and salt are not updated (I tried with **$model->save()**, but the result is the same). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have an syntax error 'true' use boolean

Answer (score 1):

It can be because of this two lines:

```
if(ActiveForm::validate($model))
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
```

Here you are checking if model data is valid, and when it is valid you just return *true*, maybe you mean

```
//the ! sign is missed
if( ! ActiveForm::validate($model))
```

and return when model data is invalid. Also look at `return 'true';` where you return string 'true' instead of boolean *true*

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to use ajax request with JSON you need to add option

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
});
```

Second, we still want JSON data

```
return ActiveForm::validate($model); // returns boolean
return 'true'; // returns string
```

You need JSON,

```
return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
    'success' => true // or something
]);
```

Third, I think you mean

```
if(!ActiveForm::validate($model))
    return false;
```